# JTable : getting data from table

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

I am trying to run this code .This contains a table which has 2 rows and 4 column and the table is for entering the marks of the student but i am constantly getting this error of nullpointer exception on line 353.  Plzzz help me 
here is the code

```
    package uclidit;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.*;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

     public class EdittedForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     String course,yearf,yeart, aggr;

    public EdittedForm() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here
        getData();

        try{
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/entryform";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root");
                String query="insert into 

     marks(course,yearf,yeart,sem1,sem2,sem3,sem4,sem5,sem6,sem7,sem8,aggregate)
               values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

                ps.setString(1,course);
               ps.setString(2,yearf);
                ps.setString(3,yeart);

                ps.setFloat(4,0);

               ps.setFloat(5,0);
                ps.setFloat(6,0);
                ps.setFloat(7,0);
                ps.setFloat(8, 0);
                ps.setFloat(9,0);
               ps.setFloat(10,0);
                ps.setFloat(11,0);
              ps.setString(12,aggr);

            ps.executeUpdate();


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                        
          public void getData()
      {



    course = jTable1.getValueAt(0,0).toString();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, course);
     yearf = jTable1.getValueAt(0,1).toString();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,yearf );
     yeart=jTable1.getValueAt(0,2).toString();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, yeart);
     aggr = jTable1.getValueAt(0,3).toString();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, aggr);

     }

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new EdittedForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane5;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane7;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane8;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane9;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable3;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable4;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable5;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable6;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable7;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable8;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable9;
    // End of variables declaration                   
   }
```

and the error is

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at uclidit.EdittedForm.getData(EdittedForm.java:353)
at uclidit.EdittedForm.jButton1ActionPerformed(EdittedForm.java:316)
at uclidit.EdittedForm.access$000(EdittedForm.java:17)
at uclidit.EdittedForm$7.actionPerformed(EdittedForm.java:251)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
```

Comment: the line in which course is initialised.

Comment: the line in which course is initialised "course = jTable1.getValueAt(0,0).toString();"

Comment: @harry19 do use netbeans ?is that netbean codes ?

Comment: @harry19 before you click the button do you see the data in cells ?or they are empty?? i guess you haven't fill `jtable` .so `valueAt()` return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, `jtable1` isn't initialised. Make sure it is. If the error persists, it is because one of the `getValue()` calls in `getData()` returns `null`. You can use `String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(0,0))` instead of `jTable1.getValueAt(0,0).toString()` to avoid `NullPointerException` in that case.

Comment: how to initialise jTable1

Comment: Look at the answer given by spcial.

Comment: Then place a breakpoint on that line and check the value of jTable1. Is it null?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the complete code? As far as I can see you declare `jTable1` but you don't initialize it. So you have to prepare or create a `jTable1` with

```
jTable1 = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

where the constructors are

```
JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames) 
JTable(Vector rowData, Vector columnNames)
```

further information here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

So I think that you get a null pointer exception at:

```
course = jTable1.getValueAt(0, 0).toString();
```

because `jTable1` is null